# No matching records found in DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am using DataTable for retrieving the data from server side. Here. NO information on DataTable. It shows   No matching records found error.

Here, oLanguage.sEmptyTable is not working and oLanguage.sZeroRecords is working  refer http://datatables.net/ref#sZeroRecords

```
var DataTableApp = $('#DataTableApp').dataTable({
    "sAjaxSource": "php/getAppDetails.php",
    "bRetrieve":true,
    "bDestroy":true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    //"bProcessing": true,
    "sAjaxDataProp": "aaData",
    //"bDeferRender": true,
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "iTotalDisplayRecords":1,
    "iTotalRecords":1,
    "oLanguage": {
      "sZeroRecords": "No records to displays"
    },


    "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
        var imei_app = document.getElementById('imei').value;
        console.log(imei_app);
        aoData.push({"name":"imei","value":imei_app});
    },
    //aoColumns
    "aoColumns": [{
        "mData": "appName"
    }, {
        "mData": "appId"
    }, {
        "mData": "versionInstalled"
    }, {
        "mData": "appSize"
    }, {
        "mData":"dataSize"
    },{
        "mData": "appType"
    },{
        "mData":"installedLocation"
    },{
        "mData": "installedTime"
    }]
});
```

Comment: Does the id DataTableApp exist at all in your html?

Comment: Surely that error comes with a backtrace, because without a trace it would be impossible to know why this happens.

Comment: Id is have. How to trace that

Comment: Does `php/getAppDetails.php` respond with the correct data?

Comment: Yes. It sends correct details

Comment: I am gettng response from server correctly, But datas are not shown in DataTable

Answer (score 4):

`oLanguage.sEmptyTable` and `oLanguage.sZeroRecords` (or in the latest format `language.emptyTable` and `language.zeroRecords`) have different purposes.

- `language.emptyTable` Displays when the table contains no rows at all.
- `language.zeroRecords` Displays when, after applying filters, there are now no records to display.

It sounds like your table had rows before filters were applied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .dataTables_empty CSS class with **display: none** attribute to your global style sheet (i.e. **src/styles.css**).

> Note: in the angular, global style sheet is located at SCSS folder (i.e. **scss/_custom.scss**).

```
.dataTables_empty {
    display: none;
  }
```

https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/server-side-angular-way